# How to find folder of application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do I find the folder where my eclipse was being installed in linux?

I can run it via console, but I dont find the folder.

Answer (score 8):

Try the `whereis` command:

```
$ whereis eclipse
eclipse: /usr/share/eclipse
```

Answer (score 4):

On a bash terminal type

```
type -a eclipse
```

Comment: This command is not what he is looking for. He searches the installation path. The result shown is only the executable. The `whereis` command is better this gives at least the directories where the parts of eclipse are. `locate` could help but can be quite confusing, as it produces just a LOT of output. And you might have to run `sudo updatedb` first. `readlink` again only gives the executable.

Comment: @Darokthar If you know where the executable is, you can look inside it (open in editor) and there is the path to the directory.

Answer (score 2):

The executable can be found in:

```
readlink -f `which eclipse`
```

`readlink` is used for symbolic links.

---

For what concern the other files i guess you can always run:

```
locate eclipse
```

to have an idea of how files are distributed in your file system.

---

Alternatively, if `eclipse` is installed from a package, you can:

```
dpkg -L eclipse
```

to list the files installed from the `eclipse` package.